# Create type guard for union type

Tags: typescript

I have a type like this:

```
type BaseType = {
  type: string
  id: string
}
```

I'm creating two types from it:

```
type TypeA = {
  type: 'TypeA'
}

type TypeB = {
  type: 'TypeB'
}
```

Then I'm creating a union type of `TypeA` and `TypeB`:

```
type ABTypes = TypeA | TypeB
```

Next, I'm creating another TypeC based on `BaseType`:

```
type TypeC = {
  type: 'TypeC'
}
```

Now I want to create a type guard for `ABTypes` like this:

```
function isABTypes(
  x: BaseType
): x is isABTypes {
  // I don't want to do this:
  return x.type === 'TypeA' || x.type === 'TypeB'
  // nor:
  return x.type !== 'TypeC'
}
```

How can I implement the type guard without having to test the `type` property for 'TypeA' and `TypeB` (which are untyped and not refactoring safe here)?

I could use this:

```
type Types = ABTypes['type']
```

which would be `'TypeA' | 'TypeB'`.

But this is a type, not a string array I can use for comparison.

The closest I could get is

```
const ABTypes = ['TypeA', 'TypeB']

function isABTypes(
  x: BaseType
): x is isABTypes {
  return ABTypes.inclues(x.type)
}
```

But this still isn't very robust when new union cases added.

Comment: User-defined type guards are not checked for correctness, so they are inherently unsafe in this regard however you write them. The best thing to do, I suggest, is always write your type guard functions immediately next to the type definition they test for, so it is less likely one will be changed without the other.

Answer (score 0):

After some iterations, this is what I have achieved. I am not sure if this is the exact solution you are looking for, but you should definitely take a look

```
// this is our base type
interface BaseType {
    type: string;
    id: string;
}

// a list of types
const ABTypes = ["TypeA", "TypeB"] as const;
// union created from above ABTypes -> type ABTypesUnion = "TypeA" | "TypeB"
type ABTypesUnion = typeof ABTypes[number];

// interface with fixed value of type
interface ABTypes extends BaseType {
    type: ABTypesUnion;
}

// test
function isABTypes(x: BaseType): x is ABTypes {
    return ABTypes.includes(x.type as ABTypesUnion);
}

const test: ABTypes = {
    type: "TypeA",
    id: "UX0001"
};

const isTestAB =  isABTypes(test);
```

You don't need to maintain the union separately.